# Could not install package 'Google.Apis.Core 1.13.1', Unable to uninstall 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21'

Tags: .net-4.0, google-api, google-calendar-api, nuget-package, google-api-dotnet-client

I have problem with Google Calendar Api. Can't install Package Google.Apis, and  Google.Apis.Auth, when Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 works. Project in .net 4.0.

```
Install-Package : Unable to uninstall 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21' because 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' depends on it.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Google.Apis
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand


Install-Package : Could not install package 'Google.Apis.Core 1.13.1'. You are trying to install this package into a projec
t that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that
 are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Google.Apis.Auth
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand


PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3
'Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 1.13.1.509' already installed.
```

The primary reference "Google.Apis.Calendar.v3, Version=1.13.1.509, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Google.Apis.Calendar.v3, Version=1.13.1.509, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

Comment: This is meant to "just work", if you look at the dependencies of Google.Apis.Calendar.v3, it depends on an older version (v1.10.0) of Google.Apis for .net4

Comment: I've just tested this with a fresh .net4 console app and it worked OK. Are you able to test with a fresh project with the same settings, and see if it works?

Comment: Or have you manually added a dependency on Google.Api (or Google.Api.Core, or Google.Api.Auth, or...) v1.13.1? If so, this will need manually removing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your project to .Net framework 4.5 and it should work.   The error message tells you exactly what the problem is.

> Could not install package 'Google.Apis.Core 1.13.1'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the **package does not contain any**
>   **assembly references or content files that  are compatible with that**
>   **framework**.

If you check the NuGet page [Google APIs Core Client Library 1.13.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Core/)

> The Google APIs Core Library contains the Google APIs HTTP layer, JSON
>   support, Data-store, logging and so on.
>
> Supported Platforms:
>
> - **.NET Framework 4.5**
> - Windows Store apps
> - Windows Phone 8 and 8.1
> - Portable Class Libraries

You will have to go back to [1.10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Core/1.10.1-rc1) to find a version that supports Framework 4.0

Home of the Google .Net Client library on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no possibility to upgrade to .net 4.5. Is there any other way to make this work?

Comment: grab an older version of the library something before the March 22 2016 release v1.11.   However you should know you wont be getting any of the changes to the API or the client library running an older version.

Comment: I would almost recommend grabbing a fork of the older version and building your own Dll that way if there are changes to the API that you need you will be able to add them to your library.  Since you wont be getting any updates from the Client library team.